# ssas 2008 how to remove total for non hierarchy dimension attributes

Tags: ssas

As you can see there is a Total added automatically. The Birth Date and Full Name are not hierarchy attributes. They are both from same dimension. I want to show birth date and full name. How to get rid of the Total?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to Compute a calculated member on your DSV. You can name it for example Birth-Name.

To do this

1. Open your Data Source View
2. Right click on the dimension name
3. New name calculation
4. Name: Birth-Name
5. expression: `birthday+' '+fullname`
6. Add the new field to your dimension
7. Preview the cube with the new calced member and money measure

In this way you can view your data and the total of all of them together
There are other ways to do this also, but this is the simplest I could think of. The total cannot be totally removed from the cube, as this is what it's real job is. To make aggregations of data.